# sort a list of dictionaries based on explicitly defined order of keys

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary for ex:

```
names = [{'Mark':'Volvo'}, {'John':'BMW'}, {'Eliza':'Merci'}, {'Calen':'Audi'}]
```

I would like to set the explicit ordering by the key names of the dictionary.

For example if I give this order:

`['John','Mark','Calen','Eliza']`

The expected output would be:

```
[{'John':'BMW'},{'Mark':'Volvo'},{'Calen':'Audi'},{'Eliza':'Merci'}]
```

I want to add a custom logic order. To be displayed through the template by their names, based on how I defined the order of their names.

Comment: What's the logic of this order? Or is the order provided separately as a list, like `['John', 'Mark', ...]` or `['BMW', 'Volvo']`?

Comment: "I would like to set the explicit ordering manually" could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: I would add that the answer is well-defined only if all dicts have exactly one element, which you may want to clarify. If so, you may be better off storing the data as a single dict ('{str: str}' if each key has one value or '{str: [str]}' if some keys have many values). Then, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key) should answer your question.

Comment: Yes, dicts have exactly one element.

Comment: But  I do not want to sort it alphabeticaly, I want to sort the way how I defined the order logic based on their keys. That is possible with orderedDict?

Comment: If your dicts have only one element each, I'd rather use tuples like `('John', 'BMW')`.

Comment: this is not sorting basically you just want the `key: value` pairs in a specific order. You have to convert your list of dictionaries to a dictionary [here is my try](https://justpaste.it/9gwsf)

Comment: I'd use tuples, could you define the code, how would you sort that list?

Comment: You could use `result = sorted(tuples, key=lambda t: (len(t[0]), t[0]))` to sort the tuples where `tuples = [(k, v) for d in names for k, v in d.items()]`.

Comment: I've provided an answer below that doesn't require tuples or OrderedDicts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, if your dictionaries only have one entry, tuples seem to be a better choice for this data:

```
>>> names = [('Mark', 'Volvo'), ('John', 'BMW'), ('Eliza', 'Merci'), ('Calen', 'Audi')]
```

Now, given this order:

```
>>> order = ['John', 'Mark', 'Calen', 'Eliza']
```

you can create a dict that maps the names to the indices:

```
>>> order_map = { k: v for v, k in enumerate(order) }
>>> order_map
{'John': 0, 'Mark': 1, 'Calen': 2, 'Eliza': 3}
```

and use it in a key function for sort:

```
>>> names.sort(key=lambda v: order_map[v[0]])
>>> names
[('John', 'BMW'), ('Mark', 'Volvo'), ('Calen', 'Audi'), ('Eliza', 'Merci')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [*Is there a way to sort a list of string by a “predicate” list?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35679676/1431750): Since `names` is a list of dictionaries with just one key-value pair each, use the `index` of the person's name in the `order` list as the key for the sort:

```
>>> names = [{'Mark': 'Volvo'}, {'John': 'BMW'}, {'Eliza': 'Merci'}, {'Calen' :'Audi'}]
>>> order = ['John', 'Mark', 'Calen', 'Eliza']
>>>
>>> # with `sorted()`
>>> sorted(names, key=lambda d: order.index(list(d.keys())[0]))
[{'John': 'BMW'}, {'Mark': 'Volvo'}, {'Calen': 'Audi'}, {'Eliza': 'Merci'}]
>>>
>>> # or with `list.sort()`
>>> names.sort(key=lambda d: order.index(list(d.keys())[0]))
>>> names
[{'John': 'BMW'}, {'Mark': 'Volvo'}, {'Calen': 'Audi'}, {'Eliza': 'Merci'}]
```

`dict.keys()` is not not subscriptable, so `dict.keys()[0]` doesn't work. So first convert that to a list and then use its one-and-only key `list(dict.keys())[0]`. That would give 'Mark', 'John', etc. Then get the index of that person's name in the `order` list. Note: it will fail if a person is not listed in `order`.

Even if `names` is a list of dictionaries with more than one key-value pair each, **as long as the person's name is the first key**, it will still work as of Python 3.7/3.6. See [the note below this item](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values):

> *Changed in version 3.7:* Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

```
>>> names = [{'Mark': 'Volvo', 'age': 30},
...          {'John': 'BMW', 'age': 40},
...          {'Eliza': 'Merci', 'age': 50},
...          {'Calen': 'Audi', 'age': 60}]
>>> sorted(names, key=lambda d: order.index(list(d.keys())[0]))
[{'John': 'BMW', 'age': 40}, {'Mark': 'Volvo', 'age': 30}, {'Calen': 'Audi', 'age': 60}, {'Eliza': 'Merci', 'age': 50}]
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
names = [{'Mark':'Volvo'}, {'John':'BMW'}, {'Eliza':'Merci'}, {'Calen':'Audi'}]
ordered_keys = ['John','Mark','Calen','Eliza']

sorted_names = [name for key in ordered_keys for name in names if key in name]
```

It iterates over the ordered_keys in order and extracts any name in the list of dict that has that key.